# Scrapy failing in terminal

Tags: python, scrapy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==0.24.4
```

I have been struggling for hours, I had different errors before, but I deleted all references to python 2.7 in my PATH, (probably a mistake), and now I'm getting new errors.

Help would be greatly appreciated on how to get Scrapy working on my mac.

Comment: How did you install Scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error says that the Scrapy Distribution that you are searching for can not be found. Try to upgrade your Scrapy by:

```
easy_install --upgrade scrapy
```

or:

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
```