# scrapy on ubuntu server

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have a problem I just cannot resolve.
After installing scrapy (with pip) I get and error when trying to make startup project:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==1.0.3.post1-g83a06ed
```

Does anyone familiar with this? I tried a lot of things including reinstalling packages.

I`m using DigitalOcean server with ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.9

Thanks,
Aviad

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this the other day:

[Scrapy failing in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614629/scrapy-failing-in-terminal)

You may need to upgrade Scrapy.

`easy_install --upgrade scrapy`

or

`pip install --upgrade scrapy`

If you don't have easy_install it can be installed with

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Comment: actually the upgrade get stuck on:Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml any idea?