# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==1.3.0

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, scrapy

I am running scrapy on my AWS-EC2 instance. But it is throwing following error.

```
$ scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 614, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 920, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Scrapy==1.3.0
```

I searched and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614629/scrapy-failing-in-terminal) But solution is not working for me. Still same error . Please help.

Comment: Reinstall scrapy and try again.

Comment: I tried 
`pip uninstall scrapy` & 
`pip install scrapy`
But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

As per the same link that you have mentioned. 
I recommend you to try with `sudo`

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade scrapy
```

or:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scrapy
```